# Issue with fonts when using Windows App form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

Evening everyone.  Looking for some help with fonts while trying to create a form in VS 2017, C# language.  It's for a school assignment.  We were tasked with recreating a message box that can be manipulated to show the fonts in different colors and different fonts.
Here is the code:

```
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Some text to change");
    }

    private void blackToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearColor();
        displayLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;  //Receive Error Code CS1061 for the "ForeColor"
        blackToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    }

    private void timesNewRomanToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearFont();

        timesNewRomanToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
        displayLabel.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14, displayLabel.Font.Style);  //Receive Error Code CS1061 for the "Font" entry.  Also receive Error Code CS1503 for the "Times New Roman" entry as well as the "Font" entry right after it.
    }

    private void boldToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearFont();

        boldToolStripMenuItem.Checked = !boldToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
        displayLabel.Font = new Font(displayLabel.Font, displayLabel.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);  //Receive Error Code CS1061 for the "Font" entries here as well.
    }
```

Not really sure what is going on, since I did literally type the code exactly as it appears in the textbook.  The rest of the code looks to be good, no red squiggly lines to be seen.  I am at a loss.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

    namespace Worldview
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private object displayLabel;
            private object timesToolStripMenuItem;
            private object comicToolStripMenuItem;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void btnShowWorldview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt", Multiselect = false, ValidateNames = true })
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
                    {
                        txtWorldview.Text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Attempted to add "public MenuTestForm" and "public displayLabel" as constructors, but that did nothing except make more errors.  Attempted to add "public partial class MenuTestForm" and "public partial class displayLabel" and both created more errors.  The button I created I know works as I tested it prior to attempting to add the menu strip.  I am most definitely sure that I am missing something blatantly obvious.

Comment: Normally you should say what the error is rather than have us look at comments in the code

Comment: I don't get an error with either of those lines. You do have a control on the form named displayLabel. Yes?

Comment: [Compiler Error CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061). - *This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist.*. Have you copied *all* the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do. Here is my guess. I made this winforms app, consisting of a strip menu (one tab for colors, one for fonts, one for effects and the about one). Then a label with a display text.

[image: Form Design]

```
private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Some text to change");
}

private void blackToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   displayLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}

private void redToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   displayLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

private void timesNewRomanToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   displayLabel.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14, displayLabel.Font.Style);
}

private void arialToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   displayLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, displayLabel.Font.Style);
}

private void boldToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   displayLabel.Font = new Font(displayLabel.Font.FontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void italicToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   displayLabel.Font = new Font(displayLabel.Font.FontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Italic);
}
```

Works fine for me. Just make sure you link the events correctly, on the "events" window.